# Baire Category situation with weakened hypotheses

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$,
converging pointwise to a function $f:[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$ which is not 
assumed to be continuous. Fix $\varepsilon >0$, and let
$F_n=\bigg\lbrace x\in [0,1] \ \bigg| \ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon\bigg\rbrace$.

A classical use of Baire's category theorem shows that some 
$\bar{F_n}$ has nonempty interior. If $f$ was assumed to be continuous
as well, then $F_n$ would be closed and have nonempty interior also.

My question : is it still true that some $F_n$ has nonempty interior
when $f$ is not assumed to be continuous ?

I tried to construct counterexamples where each $F_n$ is (some translate of) a Cantor set  but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some $F_n$ must have nonempty interior. By an application of Baire's theorem, the continuity set of $f$ is comeagre, in particular not empty.

Pick an $y$ such that $f$ is continuous at $y$, and an $n$ such that $\lvert f_n(y) - f(y)\rvert < \varepsilon/3$. By the continuity of $f$ and $f_n$ at $y$, there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $y$ such that

$$\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \lvert f_n(x) - f_n(y)\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$

for all $x\in U$. By the triangle inequality, we have $U \subset F_n$ and hence $y \in \operatorname{int} F_n$.

Comment: If I get it correctly, this argument also shows that $y \in {\rm int} F_m$ for all $m\geq n$.

Comment: Not quite, as written there can be $m > n$ with $\lvert f_m(y) - f(y)\rvert > \varepsilon$. It will be so if we choose $n$ so that $\lvert f_m(y) - f(y)\rvert < \varepsilon/3$ for all $m \geqslant n$, though.